# Probability of a linear combination of 4 independent normal distributed variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm calculating the following probability:

$P = P(F(a,b,c,d)<0)$

Where $F(a,b,c,d)$:

$F(a,b,c,d)= 1500000 - 500a - 500000b - 100000c + 5000000d$

$a, b, c$ and $d$ are independent normally distributed variables with the following means and variances:

$a: \mu = 1000$ and $\sigma = 10$

$b: \mu = 1.5$ and $\sigma = 0.5$

$c: \mu = 3.5$ and $\sigma = 1$

$d: \mu = 0.1$ and $\sigma = 0.01$

Using the rule:

$\phi N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2) + \beta N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2) = N(\phi\mu_1+\beta\mu_2,\phi^2\sigma_1^2+\beta^2\sigma_2^2)$

The equation $F(a,b,c,d)$ now simplifies to:

$F(a,b,c,d) = 1500000 + N(-500*1000-500000*1.5 - 100000*3.5 + 5000000*0.1,(-500)^2*10^2+ (-500000)^2*0.5^2 + (-100000)^2*1^2 + 5000000^2*0.01^2)= 1500000 + N(-1100000,75025000000)$

So:

$F(a,b,c,d)$ is distributed as $N(400000,75025000000)$

Now I've simulated this distribution in matlab with:

```
mu = 400000;
sigma = sqrt(75025000000);
N = 10000;
F = sigma*randn(N,1)+mu;
P = mean(F<0)
```

Which returns a value of about $0.05$. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your theory is wrong.

it is the variance $\sigma^2$ but not the standard deviation $\sigma$ that is added when you combine two independent Gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

Since random variables are all independent of each other, so the mean and variance of the required pdf is the sum of individual means and variances, respectively.